# Can I write an ant task which takes parameters when being executed from another ant task?

Tags: ant, build-process, build-automation

Can I write an ant task which takes parameters when being executed from another ant task?

What I try to achieve in general, is re-using existing tasks with
different parameters.

What I don't know is:

- is there something such a sub-task in ant?
- can it take parameters?
- how and where such sub-task is specified?

**Concept** of what I need to achieve:

**Sub Ant task**, which takes parameters param1 and param2:

```
<someAntCommand att="$param1"/>
<someOtherAntCommand att="$param2"/>
```

**Main Ant task**, which executes the sub task:

```
<doSomethingToExecSubTask somePointerToTaskOrFile="...">
    <param name="param1"> hello </param>
    <param name="param2"> world </param>
</doSomethingToExecSubTask>

<doSomethingToExecSubTask somePointerToTaskOrFile="...">
    <param name="param1"> hello </param>
    <param name="param2"> universe </param>
</doSomethingToExecSubTask>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. You can do this with [`antcall`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html).
2. Since ant 1.6, you can use [macros](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html).

Answer (score 2):

What you want is macro-def.

For a really good guide to writing Ant macros check out [this presentation](http://www.pjug.org/docs/ant.pdf).

Comment: Very good presentation indeed. Thanks for sharing. That's what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="param1"/>
<property name="param2"/>
<target name="task1">        
    <property name="param1" value="hello"/>
    <property name="param2" value="world"/>        
</target>
<target name="task2">
</target>
```

Just call task2, task run will run before it

Comment: Apologies, copy and paste error! I have edited and this should solve it